# Referring to a variable inside a class... when "this." does not work because we are in a function

Tags: javascript, click, titanium, addeventlistener

Let's say there's a class robot.

There are the variables `hand lefthand`, `hand righthand`, `leg leftleg` and `leg rightleg`.
The `leg` and `hand` classes contain `int length` and `int width`.

```
this.lefthand.length = 100;
this.leftleg.length = 200;

function switch_length () {
this.lefthand.length = 300; //This is wrong. So what can I do instead to refer to lefthand??
this.leftleg.length = 400; //This is wrong. So what can I do instead to refer to leftleg??
}

this.button.addEventlistener ( ... switch_length())
```

Comment: Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Is it applicable for Titanium? The link is for mozilla's web javascirpt.

Comment: See the Compatability section in the link.  You may also try to find the titanium documentation, if it exists.  Or just try it.  See also: http://developer.appcelerator.com/questions/newest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, you are able to define the context of functions being called. I'm better at explaining this with examples, so here it goes:

```
var something = {
    'foobar': 'var 1 value',
    'foo': function () {
        alert(this.var1);
    }
}

var something_else = {
    'foobar': 'some completely other value'
}

function bar () {
    alert(this.foobar);
}

something.foo(); //alerts 'var 1 value'
bar(); //produces an error
bar.call(something); //alerts 'var 1 value'
bar.call(something_else); //alerts 'some completely other value'
```

`function.call(context, [arg1, [arg2, [...]]]);`

If this has answered your question, please make sure to accept my answer.

Edit:
Here's another example

```
function create () {
    return  {
        'hand': {
            'length': 100
        },
        'leg': {
            'length': 100
        }
    }
}

function set_length(hand, leg) {
    this.hand.length = hand;
    this.leg.length = leg;
}

var left = create(),
    right = create();

set_length.call(left, 200, 300);
set_length.call(right, 50, 150);
```

Comment: can you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247887/titanium-javascript-that-does-not-work