# Titanium Javascript: "that." does not work

Tags: javascript, object, titanium, this

Neither this nor that works. Does anyone know what is going on??

Edit:
qwerty is simply called as "qwerty();" when in other pieces of code.
It is supposed to be indepedent.

Edit: I realize what is wrong. The problem lies with the i...

```
function qwerty () {
..... for loop that changes i ......

var that = this;
this.chara[i] = createlabel.....

this.chara[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var j = e.source.id;
    alert("hello word");
    alert(this.chara[j].width); // I get the error here
});

this.chara[i].addEventListener('doubleclick', function(e) {
    alert("hello word");
    alert(that.chara[i].width); // I get the error here too.
});
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting ? and how is this function called ?

Comment: Where is the variable i defined? The event-bound functions are asynchronous so the value of i may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any* JS problem relating to `this` is likely due to the way the function using `this` is called. Storing a reference to `this` in your `that` variable should let you reference it from within your nested functions, exactly the way you are doing it already - assuming that `qwerty()` is called in a way that sets `this` to the correct object in the first place. (Personally I like to call such a variable `self` since it more accurately reflects what the variable is doing.)

However, in your function you say you get the error on this line:

```
that.chara[i].width
```

Given that you say `this.chara[i].addEventListener(...)` I'm guessing that the `chara[i]` variable holds a reference to a DOM element. If that is the case I'm guessing it is an element type that doesn't have a `width` property. Try this:

```
that.chara[i].style.width
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/width

That's the best I can do for you without more information about what error you're getting and how the `qwerty()` function is called...

Comment: Correction to my previous comment. Still having the this/that problem even after the correction to i.